# React: is possible to get return of a function in child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have :

```
function Child() {
  const handleClick = () => 1
  return <div onClick={handleClick} >child</div>
}

function Parent(){
  // catch return from handleClick in Child
  return <div>
    <Child/>
  </div>
}
```

I want to catch the `return` from Child when click. I think I can use `useImperativeHandle()` but I don't know how to do it.

Is possible to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by `catch`? `handleClick` is defined in `Child` component and it's not accessible from `Parent`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you just pass `handleClick` as a prop to `<Child />`

```
function Child(props) {
  var someState = //...
  return <div onClick={() => props.handleClick(someState)}>child</div>
}

function Parent(){
  // catch return from handleClick in Child
  const handleClick = (value) => console.log("child clicked", value);

  return <div>
    <Child handleClick={handleClick} />
  </div>
}
```

Comment: Ex: I have an `array` **state** in `Child`. When I click in `Child`, an item of `array` is given to `Parent`. In your answer, the `array` must be stored in `Parent`. And I don't want this.

Comment: @kiman sounds like a relevant aspect of the question. I've updated the answer.

Comment: @kiman not really, as per the answer, you can pass the relevant property to the click handler. So you can pass the array value you want to the handleClick so parent can access it.

Comment: That is very simpler than I thought. Thanks you so much.